# How to create a denoising profile for darktable

Tags: post-processing, smartphone, iso-noise, darktable

I tried to create a denoising profile for my Google Nexus-5 smartphone as described [in a blog post](http://www.darktable.org/2012/12/profiling-sensor-and-photon-noise/). I shot some pictures, one per ISO setting (100,200,400,800,1600,3200) with OpenCamera which are under- and over-exposed. Then i tried to create the profile, but the script doesn't recognize the directory or the files in it.

```
~/nexus-5-iso-denoising$ ~/darktable/tools/noise/gen-profile -d .

===> Check for required tools
--> Check for images handling tools availability
--> Check for images export tools availability
--> Check for profiling tools availability
--> Check for internal tools availability
--> Build profiling tools
make: Verzeichnis „/home/tobias/darktable/tools/noise“ wird betreten
make: Für das Ziel „all“ ist nichts zu tun.
make: Verzeichnis „/home/tobias/darktable/tools/noise“ wird verlassen
--> Check for tethering tools availability
--> Check for pdf tools availability

===> Check profiling directory

===> List profiling input RAW images

Noise profiling requires at least a RAW image per required or supported
ISO setting.

Either:

    o  Plug your camera to this computer and, when detected, hit Return.
       This script will query the camera for supported ISO settings and
       take the appropriate images.

    o  Type Ctrl+C, take at least one image per supported ISO setting and
       put them in a dedicated directory. Then, re-run this script and be
       sure to indicate this directory by using the "-d" flag.

Important note about the required images:

    o  The subject must contain both under-exposed AND over-exposed
       areas. A possible subject could be a sunny window (or an in-door
       light) on half of the picture and a dark/shadowed in-door object on
       the other half.

    o  Disable auto-focus and put everything out of focus.
```

Do I need a certain file format for the raw images or do I need to name the files in a certain way?

If it's helpful: I imported the *.dng raw files in darktable applied the `raw linear` style and exported the images as jpeg,ppm,pfm:

```
~/nexus-5-iso-denoising$ ls
IMG_20170128_233116Z_100.jpg  IMG_20170128_233136Z_800.ppm   IMG_20170128_233208Z.dng        IMG_20170128_233351Z.jpg       IMG_20170128_233437Z_400.pfm
IMG_20170128_233116Z_100.pfm  IMG_20170128_233136Z.dng       IMG_20170128_233208Z.dng.xmp    IMG_20170128_233403Z_3200.jpg  IMG_20170128_233437Z_400.ppm
IMG_20170128_233116Z_100.ppm  IMG_20170128_233136Z.dng.xmp   IMG_20170128_233208Z.jpg        IMG_20170128_233403Z_3200.pfm  IMG_20170128_233437Z.dng
IMG_20170128_233116Z.dng      IMG_20170128_233136Z.jpg       IMG_20170128_233216Z_10000.jpg  IMG_20170128_233403Z_3200.ppm  IMG_20170128_233437Z.dng.xmp
IMG_20170128_233116Z.dng.xmp  IMG_20170128_233142Z_1600.jpg  IMG_20170128_233216Z_10000.pfm  IMG_20170128_233403Z.dng       IMG_20170128_233437Z.jpg
IMG_20170128_233116Z.jpg      IMG_20170128_233142Z_1600.pfm  IMG_20170128_233216Z_10000.ppm  IMG_20170128_233403Z.dng.xmp   IMG_20170128_233446Z_200.jpg
IMG_20170128_233123Z_200.jpg  IMG_20170128_233142Z_1600.ppm  IMG_20170128_233216Z.dng        IMG_20170128_233403Z.jpg       IMG_20170128_233446Z_200.pfm
IMG_20170128_233123Z_200.pfm  IMG_20170128_233142Z.dng       IMG_20170128_233216Z.dng.xmp    IMG_20170128_233413Z_1600.jpg  IMG_20170128_233446Z_200.ppm
IMG_20170128_233123Z_200.ppm  IMG_20170128_233142Z.dng.xmp   IMG_20170128_233216Z.jpg        IMG_20170128_233413Z_1600.pfm  IMG_20170128_233446Z.dng
IMG_20170128_233123Z.dng      IMG_20170128_233142Z.jpg       IMG_20170128_233334Z_10000.jpg  IMG_20170128_233413Z_1600.ppm  IMG_20170128_233446Z.dng.xmp
IMG_20170128_233123Z.dng.xmp  IMG_20170128_233147Z.jpg       IMG_20170128_233334Z_10000.pfm  IMG_20170128_233413Z.dng       IMG_20170128_233446Z.jpg
IMG_20170128_233123Z.jpg      IMG_20170128_233202Z_3200.jpg  IMG_20170128_233334Z_10000.ppm  IMG_20170128_233413Z.dng.xmp   IMG_20170128_233456Z_100.jpg
IMG_20170128_233129Z_400.jpg  IMG_20170128_233202Z_3200.pfm  IMG_20170128_233334Z.dng        IMG_20170128_233413Z.jpg       IMG_20170128_233456Z_100.pfm
IMG_20170128_233129Z_400.pfm  IMG_20170128_233202Z_3200.ppm  IMG_20170128_233334Z.dng.xmp    IMG_20170128_233424Z_800.jpg   IMG_20170128_233456Z_100.ppm
IMG_20170128_233129Z_400.ppm  IMG_20170128_233202Z.dng       IMG_20170128_233334Z.jpg        IMG_20170128_233424Z_800.pfm   IMG_20170128_233456Z.dng
IMG_20170128_233129Z.dng      IMG_20170128_233202Z.dng.xmp   IMG_20170128_233351Z_6400.jpg   IMG_20170128_233424Z_800.ppm   IMG_20170128_233456Z.dng.xmp
IMG_20170128_233129Z.dng.xmp  IMG_20170128_233202Z.jpg       IMG_20170128_233351Z_6400.pfm   IMG_20170128_233424Z.dng       IMG_20170128_233456Z.jpg
IMG_20170128_233129Z.jpg      IMG_20170128_233208Z_6400.jpg  IMG_20170128_233351Z_6400.ppm   IMG_20170128_233424Z.dng.xmp   presets.json
IMG_20170128_233136Z_800.jpg  IMG_20170128_233208Z_6400.pfm  IMG_20170128_233351Z.dng        IMG_20170128_233424Z.jpg
IMG_20170128_233136Z_800.pfm  IMG_20170128_233208Z_6400.ppm  IMG_20170128_233351Z.dng.xmp    IMG_20170128_233437Z_400.jpg
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Keep in mind that right now, darktable ships with some Nexus 5 noise profile already. Did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

From here http://www.darktable.org/resources/camera-support/ it seems DNG is supported.

Do your files have the correct rights (can gen-profile read them) ? Check that with `ls -al`. If they don't, do a `chmod 644`, or change ownership.